# Does Change Data Capture have a mechanism to output all existing records when it is turned on?

Tags: change-data-capture

When you have an org that already contains records, is there a way to make Change Data Capture (CDC) emit "create" changes for all the existing records when it is first turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. CDC only goes forward, the same as if you just deployed a new Record-Triggered Flow or other automations. You'll still need to mirror the data in a traditional manner (i.e. query every record in the database for the object(s) you're interested in).

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't see anything in the docs so not too surprising.